# Android service without lock considered useless?

Tags: android, android-service, kotlin-coroutines

According to Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Service):

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

But my service get killed very quickly - around 10 seconds - when the user leaves the app or the screen gets turn off. It seems according to [Android Kotlin Foreground Service stops after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618284/android-kotlin-foreground-service-stops-after-some-time) that you need some sort of mechanism to prevent the phone from getting in doze mode.

So, what is the purpose of having a service without a wake lock? And why does the documentation never mention something remotely related to wake lock when dealing with services?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Service` that is doing work for an `Activity`. If the user navigates away from the app or dims the screen or ignores his phone long enough for it to be clear that he isn't looking at it, what is the point of the `Service` continuing to run? The user isn't looking at the `Activity`, so processing in the `Service` is not important enough to keep the phone from sleeping.

On the other hand, if you have a `Service` that is performing important work and you need to keep the phone from going to sleep, then you obviously need to get some kind of wake lock or use some other method to keep the phone on.

These are 2 different scenarios with different requirements.

Comment: I need to execute a long living task such as getting data from a serial device. It cannot be interrupted nor stopped. This task should run in a local thread or as from definition in a service. But this service doesn't live up to it's definition as it's killed almost instantly. Why a service then? A normal thread will suffice.

Comment: Well, you obviously have a task that needs to keep the device awake, so you need a wake lock. This is a very specific kind of use of the device and one that is outside of the normal application behaviour on consumer smartphones. You seem to have a problem with the documentation and I agree, there are issues with the documentation. However this seems to cover most of the issues a developer might encounter: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock